# MP4 video set to autoplay for the users. Using commonly used methods, it still doesn't autoplay?

Tags: javascript, html, video

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am working on a website in which I want to display its features using a looped mp4 video.

Here is what I used to create this element:

```
<video width="1500" height="1000" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
              <source src="/assets/images/hero/videoexample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
            </video>
```

When I did this, no matter what I changed, I would still get the below result:

[image: Issue with autoplay]

It would never automatically play the video to then not allow it to be looped.

This website is built on: HTML, JS, SCSS, CSS, and Primarily Bootstrap.
I hope this information helps.

Any advice on what I should do would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add event listener `oncanplay`.

Take a look inline example:

```html
<video width="1500" height="1000" autoplay loop muted playsinline oncanplay="() => {
    this.muted = true;
    this.play();
}"
>
 <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Comment: So this video actually ended up frozen as well oddly

Comment: Even with the code snippet. Would it help to know that the front-end is built in Bootstrap?

Comment: Try to update chrome!

Comment: For me, its already up to date!

Comment: Basic platform is  HTML, JS, CSS all other are just frameworks , libs ... Do you use chrome or some other browser ? On lower level your problem can be connected with video encoder problems specially on older mashines.

Comment: I use the latest browser update for Chrome on a modern computer. RTX 2070, i7 9700k

Comment: In that case you need to prepare more info about your source code, somebody on community will find it what is it ! Did your page need autoplay on load if not you can use first touch/click to load video with sound Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378805/mp4-video-in-html5-video-tag-not-playing-in-mobile-chrome-and-mobile-safari/42268108#42268108